# How to convert a std::map to a std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, stl

A `std::map<K,V>` implements a *partial* function of type `std::function<V(K)>`.

I am trying to implement a generic function `map2fun()` that turns a `std::map` into a `std::function` object.

The following does not compile:

```
template<typename M>
function<M::mapped_type(M::key_type)> map2fun(M& m)
{
  return [&m](M::key_type k)
    {
      return m[k];
    };
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a similar functionality available in the STL for C++11?
- If not, how can I implement it with C++11?

Comment: Is it intentional to return value and not reference ? Is it intentional to allow to modify the map ?

Comment: @Jarod42 As of my current state of learning: no, it is not intentional.

Comment: @ziggystar - answer improved (following a Jarod42's comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a similar functionality available in the STL for C++11?

No, as far I know.

But the `std::map` itself is "a similar functionality available in the STL for C++11" (and also C++98), IMHO.

> If not, how can I implement it with C++11?

Adding some `typename`'s to your code, by example

```
template <typename M>
std::function<typename M::mapped_type(typename M::key_type)> map2fun (M & m)
 { return [&m](typename M::key_type k) { return m[k]; }; }
```

But I find clearer this way

```
template <typename K, typename V>
std::function<V(K)> m2f2 (std::map<K, V> & m)
 { return [&m](K k) { return m[k]; }; }
```

but, as pointed by Jarod42 (thanks!), this intercept `std::map` only (not `std::unordered_map`, not similar (also custom) types), so you can make it more flexyble as follows

```
template <template <typename ...> class C, typename K, typename V,
          typename ... Ts>
std::function<V(K)> m2f2 (C<K, V, Ts...> & m)
 { return [&m](K k) { return m[k]; }; }
```

and, starting from C++17, con be simplified as follows

```
template <template <typename ...> class C, typename K, typename V>
std::function<V(K)> m2f2 (C<K, V> & m)
 { return [&m](K k) { return m[k]; }; }
```

As pointer by Jarod42 (thanks again!) this template-template version is enabled also for other containers (`std::vector`, by example) and this give a very ugly error message (not the plain and simple "map2fun() not implemented).

You can avoid this problem, using SFINAE, enabling the function only (by example) if the `C` container define a `mapped_type` type; I mean

```
template <template <typename ...> class C, typename K, typename V,
          typename ... Ts, typename = typename C<K, V, Ts...>::mapped_type>
std::function<V(K)> m2f2 (C<K, V, Ts...> & m)
 { return [&m](K k) { return m[k]; }; }
```

But now my simpler version is more complicated that your original one :( .

The following is a full working double example

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>

template <typename M>
std::function<typename M::mapped_type(typename M::key_type)> m2f1 (M & m)
 { return [&m](typename M::key_type k) { return m[k]; }; }

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename K, typename V,
          typename ... Ts, typename = typename C<K, V, Ts...>::mapped_type>
std::function<V(K)> m2f2 (C<K, V, Ts...> & m)
 { return [&m](K k) { return m[k]; }; }

int main ()
 {
   std::map<int, long> m1 {{0, 1L}, {1, 2L}, {2, 4L}, {3, 8L}};
   std::unordered_map<int, long> m2 {{0, 1L}, {1, 2L}, {2, 4L}, {3, 8L}};

   auto l1 { m2f1(m1) };
   auto l2 { m2f2(m2) };
   auto l3 { m2f1(m1) };
   auto l4 { m2f2(m2) };

   std::cout << l1(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << l2(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << l3(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << l4(2) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: beat me to it :(

Comment: @UmNyobe - Sorry :-)

Comment: First way would also allow `std::unordered_map` without extra overload BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 - You're right; but template-templates and variadic templates can help. Answer modified. Thanks!

Comment: You now accept `std::vector`, even if you would have error inside the function.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes... a very ugly error... added a SFINAE enabled version to intercept only types with a `mapped_type` inside it... but now my simplified version is more complicated that the OP original one :(

Comment: I would stay with specific versions for `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` which are the most readable and should be enough in most case.